# org-return-follows-link with footnotes?

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks

I want to follow footnote links in org-mode by positioning the point over the link and hitting the `return` key.

In my `init.el` file, I have `(setq org-return-follows-link t)` which works fine for regular org-mode links but has no effect on footnotes, i.e., links of the form `[fn:1]`.

Any ideas?

**Update**

I had an idea to add something like this to my `init.el`. But it's not working quite yet...

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<return>")
                (condition-case nil
                    (org-open-at-point)
                  (error (execute-kbd-macro (read-kbd-macro "<return>")))
                  ))
```

Comment: The built-in commands for following a footnote link are described in the manual:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Footnotes.html  Someone may wish to add this new `return` key feature, which can *probably* done without opening up a Pandora's Box [?].

Comment: Thanks @lawlist. Hey, I just added some code (above). It's not working yet. But maybe you have some insights?

Comment: @Adam Look at the documentation for functions `global-set-key` and the lower-level `define-key` (`C-h f <function-name> RET`). You should place the `condition-case` form within an [`interactive`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Call.html) command, whether named (`defun`) or otherwise (`lambda`).

Comment: Thanks Basil. Can you elaborate on how to use `interactive` in this case?

Comment: @Adam See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Writing-Defuns.html#Writing-Defuns), in particular [this section](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Interactive.html).

Comment: You essentially need something like `(lambda () (interactive) (condition-case ...))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a new condition to `org-return`, very similar to how it handles a link containing the `org-link` face property ..., with the new condition being triggered if the `org-footnote` face property is present.  We use `org-footnote-action` to jump to/from.  The code is from Org version 8.2.10 that ships with Emacs 25.2.1.

```lisp
(require 'org)

(setq org-return-follows-link t)

(defun org-return (&optional indent)
  "Goto next table row or insert a newline.
Calls `org-table-next-row' or `newline', depending on context.
See the individual commands for more information."
  (interactive)
  (let (org-ts-what)
    (cond
      ((or (bobp) (org-in-src-block-p))
        (if indent (newline-and-indent) (newline)))
      ((org-at-table-p)
        (org-table-justify-field-maybe)
        (call-interactively 'org-table-next-row))
      ;; when `newline-and-indent' is called within a list, make sure
      ;; text moved stays inside the item.
      ((and (org-in-item-p) indent)
        (if (and (org-at-item-p) (>= (point) (match-end 0)))
          (progn
            (save-match-data (newline))
            (org-indent-line-to (length (match-string 0))))
          (let ((ind (org-get-indentation)))
            (newline)
            (if (org-looking-back org-list-end-re)
                (org-indent-line)
              (org-indent-line-to ind)))))
      ((and org-return-follows-link
        (org-at-timestamp-p t)
        (not (eq org-ts-what 'after)))
          (org-follow-timestamp-link))
      ((and org-return-follows-link
            (let ((tprop (get-text-property (point) 'face)))
              (or (eq tprop 'org-link)
                  (and (listp tprop) (memq 'org-link tprop)))))
         (call-interactively 'org-open-at-point))
      ;;; NEW CONDITION:  `org-footnote' face property => `org-footnote-action'
      ((and org-return-follows-link
            (let ((tprop (get-text-property (point) 'face)))
              (or (eq tprop 'org-footnote)
                  (and (listp tprop) (memq 'org-footnote tprop)))))
         (org-footnote-action))
      ((and (org-at-heading-p)
            (looking-at
              (org-re "\\([ \t]+\\(:[[:alnum:]_@#%:]+:\\)\\)[ \t]*$")))
        (org-show-entry)
        (end-of-line 1)
        (newline))
     (t
        (if indent
          (newline-and-indent)
          (newline))))))
```